# organized workingspace in c# form

Tags: c#, forms, transition

it's my first time in C# form and I dont know if what I am doing is correct.
below is my form workspace in C# and you can see that there's a lot of things there and it's messy...
[image]

i use the this.BackgroundImage = image; to change the background image of the form and i just turn the visible property of each control on whenever they are needed so that it look nice when i run the app (im still not finish with it though, it's hard to work in a form that's messy)
[image]

is there anyway i can work in an organized way like i could work with a lot of forms, instead of one, and just interconnect them like in powerpoint where you could have many slides and just use a hyperlink to point to other slides... please help...
and here's my code (sorry for the noob coding style)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace PProj1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backfromaboutandhow.Visible = false;
            nextbutton.Visible = false;
            backfromreserve.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            textBox3.Visible = false;
            textBox4.Visible = false;
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            finish.Visible = false;
            backtoreserve.Visible = false;
            N1.Visible = false;
            N2.Visible = false;
            N3.Visible = false;
            N4.Visible = false;
            N5.Visible = false;
            N6.Visible = false;
            N7.Visible = false;
            N8.Visible = false;
            S1.Visible = false;
            S2.Visible = false;
            S3.Visible = false;
            S4.Visible = false;
            S5.Visible = false;
            S6.Visible = false;
            S7.Visible = false;
            S8.Visible = false;
            E1.Visible = false;
            E2.Visible = false;
            E3.Visible = false;
            E4.Visible = false;
            W1.Visible = false;
            W2.Visible = false;
            W3.Visible = false;
            NW1.Visible = false;
            NW2.Visible = false;
            NE1.Visible = false;
            NE2.Visible = false;
            SW.Visible = false;
            SE.Visible = false;
        }

        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet ds;

        private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aboutoldtrafford.Location = new Point(16, 9);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aboutoldtrafford.Location = new Point(9, 9);
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            howtogetthere.Location = new Point(16, 62);
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            howtogetthere.Location = new Point(9, 62);
        }

        private void pictureBox3_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reserveaticket.Location = new Point(16, 113);
        }

        private void pictureBox3_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reserveaticket.Location = new Point(9, 113);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = Properties.Resources.about;
            this.BackgroundImage = image;
            aboutoldtrafford.Visible = false;
            howtogetthere.Visible = false;
            reserveaticket.Visible = false;
            backfromaboutandhow.Visible = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox4_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backfromaboutandhow.Location = new Point(566, 511);
        }

        private void pictureBox4_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backfromaboutandhow.Location = new Point(559, 511);
        }

        private void pictureBox4_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            backfromaboutandhow.Visible = false;
            Image image = Properties.Resources.oldtraffordwelcome1;
            this.BackgroundImage = image;
            aboutoldtrafford.Visible = true;
            howtogetthere.Visible = true;
            reserveaticket.Visible = true;

        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = Properties.Resources.howto;
            this.BackgroundImage = image;
            aboutoldtrafford.Visible = false;
            howtogetthere.Visible = false;
            reserveaticket.Visible = false;
            backfromaboutandhow.Visible = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = Properties.Resources.reg1;
            this.BackgroundImage = image;
            aboutoldtrafford.Visible = false;
            howtogetthere.Visible = false;
            reserveaticket.Visible = false;
            backfromaboutandhow.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            nextbutton.Visible = true;
            backfromreserve.Visible = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox5_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nextbutton.Location = new Point(545, 463);
        }

        private void pictureBox5_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nextbutton.Location = new Point(539, 463);
        }

        private void pictureBox6_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backfromreserve.Location = new Point(30, 463);
        }

        private void pictureBox6_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backfromreserve.Location = new Point(36, 463);
        }

        private void pictureBox6_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            nextbutton.Visible = false;
            backfromreserve.Visible = false;
            Image image = Properties.Resources.oldtraffordwelcome1;
            this.BackgroundImage = image;
            aboutoldtrafford.Visible = true;
            howtogetthere.Visible = true;
            reserveaticket.Visible = true;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            textBox3.Visible = false;
            textBox4.Visible = false;
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            finish.Visible = false;
            backtoreserve.Visible = false;

        }

        private void pictureBox5_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "")
            {
                Image image = Properties.Resources.reg21;
                this.BackgroundImage = image;

                textBox1.Visible = false;
                textBox2.Visible = false;
                textBox3.Visible = false;
                textBox4.Visible = false;
                label1.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = false;
                label4.Visible = false;
                label5.Visible = false;
                nextbutton.Visible = false;
                backfromreserve.Visible = false;
                finish.Visible = true;
                backtoreserve.Visible = true;
                N1.Visible = true;
                N2.Visible = true;
                N3.Visible = true;
                N4.Visible = true;
                N5.Visible = true;
                N6.Visible = true;
                N7.Visible = true;
                N8.Visible = true;
                S1.Visible = true;
                S2.Visible = true;
                S3.Visible = true;
                S4.Visible = true;
                S5.Visible = true;
                S6.Visible = true;
                S7.Visible = true;
                S8.Visible = true;
                E1.Visible = true;
                E2.Visible = true;
                E3.Visible = true;
                E4.Visible = true;
                W1.Visible = true;
                W2.Visible = true;
                W3.Visible = true;
                NW1.Visible = true;
                NW2.Visible = true;
                NE1.Visible = true;
                NE2.Visible = true;
                SW.Visible = true;
                SE.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                label5.Visible = true;
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection(@" provider=Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; data source=C:\OldTrafford.accdb; Persist Security Info=False");
            loaddata();
        }
        void loaddata()
        {
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from oldtraff", con);
            ds = new DataSet(); //student-> table name in stud.accdb file
            adapter.Fill(ds, "oldtraff");
            ds.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("pk_ID", ds.Tables[0].Columns[0], true);//creating primary key for Tables[0] in dataset
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void finish_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            finish.Location = new Point(545, 553);
        }

        private void finish_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            finish.Location = new Point(539, 553);
        }

        private void backtoreserve_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backtoreserve.Location = new Point(30, 553);
        }

        private void backtoreserve_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backtoreserve.Location = new Point(36, 553);
        }

        private void backtoreserve_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = Properties.Resources.reg1;
            this.BackgroundImage = image;
            aboutoldtrafford.Visible = false;
            howtogetthere.Visible = false;
            reserveaticket.Visible = false;
            backfromaboutandhow.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            nextbutton.Visible = true;
            backfromreserve.Visible = true;
            finish.Visible = false;
            backtoreserve.Visible = false;
            N1.Visible = false;
            N2.Visible = false;
            N3.Visible = false;
            N4.Visible = false;
            N5.Visible = false;
            N6.Visible = false;
            N7.Visible = false;
            N8.Visible = false;
            S1.Visible = false;
            S2.Visible = false;
            S3.Visible = false;
            S4.Visible = false;
            S5.Visible = false;
            S6.Visible = false;
            S7.Visible = false;
            S8.Visible = false;
            E1.Visible = false;
            E2.Visible = false;
            E3.Visible = false;
            E4.Visible = false;
            W1.Visible = false;
            W2.Visible = false;
            W3.Visible = false;
            NW1.Visible = false;
            NW2.Visible = false;
            NE1.Visible = false;
            NE2.Visible = false;
            SW.Visible = false;
            SE.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably consider using "User Controls" to separate your screens. Each of these controls should manage it's own interactions with the user. If you need to let you main form know what's going on with one of these controls, you can use an event (just like any other type of control).

For the example you've shown, you'd have 5 controls (one for each screen), and maybe a few events on each control which indicate the user has pressed the "Next" button (or whatever).

The main control should change which control is displayed at any given time... and it'll probably be easiest to do this through code instead of the GUI designer.

EDIT:

This link is super old, but it'll give you an idea of what I mean - and save me from making a bunch of screen shots and pasting them in here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx

http://knol.google.com/k/creating-custom-controls-with-c-net#

Comment: yes, i use events to change my screen like turn off other controls and change the background image of the form if that's what you mean. but still my "workspace" form is still cluttered with controls since i cannot hide them while the app is not running

Comment: I think you misunderstand. You should create several of your own controls - these controls will contain all of the controls you currently have on your single form which belong to one distinct "screen". The new "screen controls" you'll create will have their own, new, events - such as "NextScreen".

Comment: i think that's what i need. unfortunately, i dont know how to do that, can you please cite an example?

Comment: The second link is a slightly more up-to-date (and C#) reference. If you like my answer, I'd be very appreciative if you would consider giving me the answer credit by clicking the checkbox under the voting arrows on my post :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make [wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195255/best-wizard-control-for-net-windows-forms/195263#195263) like your application.  Also as others mentioned in their answers use user controls to "group" controls to manage them easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a usercontrol for each and simply hide/show that usercontrol.

Comment: when you say usercontrol, does it mean events? because i use them and they hide/show controls when i click something while the program is running. but what if the program is not running and i am still editing? i can still see all the controls in my case

Comment: @Roj Beraña. By usercontrol I mean that you need to make a new usercontrol by adding that item to project. Hence at each time what you see on the window is a usercontrol containing the various other controls. When you click Next or Back you would then see a different usercontrol containing other controls. Hence all you need to do is that on Next or Back button click, just show a particular usercontrol and hide the rest. In this way using usercontrol you can group items visible on the screen at a particular time. You can handle events of each usercontrol in it's cs file.